# mPDF - Show background only on odd pages

Tags: css-selectors, mpdf

Using mPDF, I'm trying to apply a background image only on odd pages.

**This works (only odd pages will be red):**

```
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', 'red');
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', 'white');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
```

**But this does not work (background is showing on both page 1 and 2):**

```
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', 'url(\'./pdf-bg.png\')');
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', 'none');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Using named pages (e.g. @page oddpage), it completely changed the page parameters and broke the layout
- Using @page :first, I can't use :first as I need every odd page to have a background, not only the first one

**Any clue? Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a workaround, not my favorite solution but it does the job!

```
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image', 'pdf-bg.png');
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resize', 6);
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resolution', '300dpi');
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image', 'pdf-bg-white.png'); // Reset background to a blank page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML('test');
```

So basically using the `background-image` CSS property instead of `background` and resetting the background with a full-white background to emulate a blank page.